# Erlide: how to run all project eunit-tests at once?

Tags: unit-testing, automation, erlang

I just started to develop (from scratch) a new project in Erlang. I use Erlide, a plugin for Eclipse. I wrote some unit tests (using EUnit) but I find running each of them (one by one) by hand quite annoying. Is there any way to automate this process, so that - with just a couple of clicks - all of my tests are run?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run all test in a directory you can use the primitive:

```
{dir, Path::string()}
```

> This tests all object files in the specified directory, as if they had been individually specified using {file, FileName}.

You can also use the `file`and `application` primitive and others to define sets of tests.

You'll find documentation to all these under [1.5  EUnit test representation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#id56578)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Defining a function run () -> eunit:test({dir, "my-newbie-project/ebin"}). in an appropriate module (like all_tests, for example) works as intended. I still see a room for improvement, though. Currently I have to manually run the eunit:test({dir, "my-newbie-project/ebin"}) expression in the Erlide console; for some reason, I cannot make it run as an Erlide run configuration. Any ideas on how to make it work?